# How to pass linux kernel cmdline in pmon2000 2.1 command prompt

Tags: bootloader, firmware

I have Lemote Yeeloong 8089d laptop, with pmon2000 firmware (version line: "PMON2000 2.1 (Bonito) #14: Tue May 18 10:33:47 CST 2010"). In file boot.cfg I can write something like

```
title 1
 kernel (wd0,0)/vmlinux
 args root=/dev/sda1 quiet ro
 initrd (wd0,0)/initrd
```

I can also load kernel and initrd in the command prompt like

```
initrd (wd0,0)/initrd
boot -k (wd0,0)/vmlinux
```

But without kernel cmdline "root=/dev/sda1 quiet ro". How do I pass this?